# CoreOS HP410 RAID1 device not added (-19)

Tags: command-line, ssd, raid

i face problem 'addition failed -19, device not added'

```
  > hpsa 0000:07:00.0: addition failed -19, device not added.
  > HP P410 controller SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
```

This hpssacli sees no devices. How to remove the message from the console?

P.S. SSD is not, I do not know why he is trying to add them